# Postgresql "no transaction in progress"

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions

Why am I getting a warning about "no transaction in progress" after a `COMMIT` even when I have explicitly started a transaction with `START TRANSACTION` (works the same as `BEGIN`)? This will occur 90% of the time for this specific transaction, but other times the commit will succeed. I'm using postgres 9.3. Here's the postgres log:

```
2014-07-04 21:47:19 EST LOG:  statement: START TRANSACTION;
2014-07-04 21:47:19 EST LOG:  statement: SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
2014-07-04 21:47:19 EST LOG:  statement: SET autocommit = 1;
2014-07-04 21:47:19 EST LOG:  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'
2014-07-04 21:47:19 EST LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "Users" (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING *;
2014-07-04 21:47:19 EST LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "Profiles" (...) RETURNING *;
2014-07-04 21:47:19 EST LOG:  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'
2014-07-04 21:47:19 EST LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "Sessions" (...) VALUES (...) RETURNING *;
2014-07-04 21:47:20 EST LOG:  statement: COMMIT;
2014-07-04 21:47:20 EST WARNING:  there is no transaction in progress
```

Comment: Sure they're the same session? Add `%p` to `log_line_prefix` and retry. Also, what client library, client app?

Comment: The session IDs are different for the `START TRANSACTION`-`COMMIT` pair that fails, and they are the same for the times when it works. Could that be the problem? Do the sessions need to be the same? Sorry if that's a dumb question; I don't know how transactions work behind-the-scenes. I'm using a beta version 2.0.0 [sequelizejs](http://sequelizejs.com) ORM with node, which could be the problem, but I have been using it for some time without any issues and then this started happening randomly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using autocommit. When using autocommit, explicitly starting a transaction is meaningless.

Remove the line "set autocommit = 1" or change the 1 to "off" or an equivalent value and this should work.

Comment: "*When using autocommit, explicitly starting a transaction is meaningless.*" - that is not true.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Depends on the autocommit implementation in the driver. In many of them, it'd be the same as `BEGIN; COMMIT;` - or `BEGIN; BEGIN; COMMIT;`.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name: Quote postgres documentation on autocommit: "This command can change the session to autocommit mode, where each individual statement is committed implicitly." This means, that each statement ist basically the same as BEGIN; statement; COMMIT;

Thus, adding extra BEGIN; COMMIT; commands doesn't change anything.

Comment: The [postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-begin.html) says: 'By default **(without `BEGIN`)**, PostgreSQL executes transactions in "autocommit" mode, that is, each statement is executed in its own transaction and a commit is implicitly performed at the end of the statement (if execution was successful, otherwise a rollback is done)'. If I'm using `BEGIN` then autocommit doesn't mean anything since I'm explicitly telling postgres the begin and end of the transaction, right?